# Getting an array of input values with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am selecting all input elements with class "img-title" in order to get an array with the current value of these inputs:

```
var values = []
for (let element of $(".img-title")){ 
   values.push( element.val() ) }
```

But this doesn't work, because the elements of `$(".img-title")` are not the references to the inputs as I expected, but the html code, so `val()` rises an error. Is there a simple way to get the array with the current values of the inputs with class "img-title" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `for..of` over a jQuery collection, the items you get back are the elements themselves, not a jQuery collection which contains that element. Either turn the element into a jQuery collection first before calling `.val()` on it:

```
const values = []
for (const element of $(".img-title")){ 
  values.push( $(element).val() )
}
```

Or, access the property on the native element just with `.value`:

```
const values = []
for (const element of $(".img-title")){ 
  values.push( element.value )
}
```

Or, consider using `.map` instead:

```
const values = $(".img-title")
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  })
  .get();
```

(make sure to use `.get()` at the end, to get the array, rather than the jQuery collection)

Or, avoid jQuery entirely if you want, no need to include a big library for something as simple as this:

```
const values = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.img-title'),
  element => element.value
);
```